# Where did the galaxy live wallpaper go in ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, live-wallpaper

Since I've upgraded to Ice Cream Sandwich on my Nexus S, the galaxy live wallpaper -  which was part of Android - is gone.

Can I get the exact same live wallpaper for ice cream sandwich? It looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? Is the question not clear?

Comment: Pure speculation (that's why this is a comment rather than an answer): perhaps that wallpaper was found to use up too much CPU or something, so they yanked it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to switch your current live wallpapers with the Gingerbread pack the Nexus S came with. This will need your device to be rooted though.

As seen on [this topic on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=9813313), you can use [Root Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) (or any other application that can get into the android filesystem, like [Root Browser Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree)) to switch your with livewallpaper.apk file located on *system/app* with [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=464315&d=1292351636), which contains the stock Gingerbread live wallpapers from the Nexus S, and possibly the one you're looking for.

--

Also, there's some really similar live wallpapers available on the Market, including one called [Galaxy Core 3D LiveWallpaper](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jarodyv.livewallpaper.galaxies), which looks almost like the one you're looking for.
[image]